# Duplicate Cell A if Columns contain data, Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have data that is in the following format

```
CardMinder  5   4.1         
Citrix Authentication Manager   6   5.1 7   8   5
Citrix Receiver Inside  4.2 4.1 4.3 4.4 4
```

I'm trying to write some code that will take this and add the first column multiple times to each column after that.

Example

```
CardMinder  5
CardMinder  4.1
```

I have some working code but it only works on one row at a time, and it adds multiple empty rows in between lines if I run it twice. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Your help is appreciated.

```
Sub createVersions()
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = ActiveSheet


'Loop through columns in Excel sheet
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Integer, c As Integer, r As Long

LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).row
LastCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column


   For r = 1 To LastRow
      If (LastCol > 2) Then
      'Check column 3 to end for contents
         For c = 3 To LastCol
            rngParent = sheet.Cells(r, "A").Value
            initChild = sheet.Cells(r, c).Value

               If (initChild <> "") Then
                  'insert a row for extra column data
                  ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
                  sheet.Cells(r + 1, "A").Value = rngParent
                  sheet.Cells(r + 1, "B").Value = initChild
               End If
            Next c
         End If
   Next r
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand you are just trying to get a two column list that has every combination of the item from the 1st column with every number in the columns following that item. It's possible to do that within the data set, but honestly it's much simpler if we write it out into a new sheet instead. It only take some minor modifications to your existing code to have it do that.

```
Sub createVersions()
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = ActiveSheet

'Use a new sheet instead of messing with the base data
Dim wsVersionList As Worksheet
Set wsVersionList = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add

'Loop through columns in Excel sheet
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Integer, c As Integer, r As Long

LastRow = sheet.UsedRange.Rows(sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
LastCol = sheet.UsedRange.Columns(sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column

Dim CurRow As Long
CurRow = 1

For r = 1 To LastRow
   If (LastCol > 2) Then
   'Check column 2 to end for contents
      For c = 2 To LastCol
         rngParent = sheet.Cells(r, "A").Value
         initChild = sheet.Cells(r, c).Value

            If (initChild <> "") Then
                'Write the software and verison values into the scratch sheet
                wsVersionList.Cells(CurRow, 1) = rngParent
                wsVersionList.Cells(CurRow, 2) = initChild
                'Increment to the next row
                CurRow = CurRow + 1
            End If
         Next c
      End If
Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: OH I got it to work just had to change the workbook call to Set wsVersionList = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add

Thank you for the help